# Paypal Error - "Total of cart item amounts to not match order amounts"

Tags: php, paypal

I am getting the following error:

> SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Detailed Error Message: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.Short Error Message: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.Error Code: 10413Error Severity Code: Error

Data being passed is:

> ```
> L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0 value=6
> L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0  value=17.99
> L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0 value=Nautilus Mini Tank
> L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0 value=1
> L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1 value=3
> L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1  value=14.99
> L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1 value=Vision Spinner II
> L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1 value=1
> PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT  value=32.98
> PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT value=3.99
> PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT value=0
> PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT value=3.99
> PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT value=0
> PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT value=32.98
> currencyCodeType value=GBP
> paymentType value=Sale
> PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT value=0
> ```

My understanding is that each product (the prefix L_ is per product) has a total item price and a total item quantity.  This is multiplied an should equal ITEMAMT (which it does) and then the grand total with shipping etc is AMT - which is correct as shipping is 3.99 and the discount is 3.99

What am I doing wrong?

The syntax is correct I think as it did work for 1 product it's just giving me trouble when I try more than 1.

Comment: Ah, the discount amount has to be negative!